# Stop case owner from changing when using the "Stopped" checkbox

Tags: case, entitlements, casemilestone, owner

I am using milestones for cases and when I change the value of the checkbox "Stopped" (when I check or uncheck it), the owner of the case goes back to the default queue.
Is it possible to avoid this? I would want the case to keep the same owner.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You must be having some workflow or trigger which assigns the case to queue, 
It is not a standard functionality. 
please check the triggers/workflows/process on case.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason, it can be inside your "Assignment rules"
In some cases, Assignment rules work on EVERY update (not only with first create)
because of that my assignment rules looks like that:

```
1
Case: Assignment Rules Done EQUALS True
Same User
2
(Entitlement: Support Level EQUALS Proactive) AND (Case: Assignment Rules Done EQUALS False)
Proactive Queue 
3
(Entitlement: Support Level EQUALS Premium) AND (Case: Assignment Rules Done EQUALS False)
Premium Queue
```